# ZwQueryDirectoryFile Behaviour

Tags: c, winapi, api, filesystems

I get to know from msdn documentations about [ZWQueryDirectoryFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff567047%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) APIs usage.
I am puzzled with one particular functionality in it.

Case: My application only involves NT level APIs.  I have to fetch the files and directories in a specified parent directory with ZwQueryDirectoryFile.  I have to allocate buffer with a length which is unknown. So I would like to do it by allocating 4096 and get the entities fit for the size and have to allocate further to get the remaining till ERROR_NO_MORE_FILES.
FindNextFile uses the same concept by calling ZWQueryDirectoryFIle phase by Phase with buffer length 4096. So I assumed, the requirement  is definitely feasible through querydirectoryfile api.
My problem is When I call Query directory file for the second time, I dont know how to inform the ZwQueryDirectoryFile api  to resume from the previous fetching state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass `FALSE` in the `RestartScan` argument. From the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff567047.aspx):

> *RestartScan* [in]
>
> Set to `TRUE` if the scan is to start at the first entry in the
>   directory. Set to `FALSE` if resuming
>   the scan from a previous call.

Comment: @Rajakymar, The first call to `ZwQueryDirectoryFile()` will only return `ERROR_SUCCESS` if the buffer is large enough to accommodate at least one entry. If it doesn't, you should allocate a bigger buffer. On subsequent calls, the function will set the `Information` member of the passed `IO_STATUS_BLOCK` structure to `0` if the buffer is not large enough. If you follow these hints, it should work.

Comment: thank u for ur help.it works to me,i have an doubt remain in this api behaviour ,that was where it have to save the last data entry offset in first call of zwquerydirectoryfile..either in registry or in the same fn arguments? how it pass the offset of data to resume from previous state in 2nd call of zwquerydirectoryfile..Let me know if you know about it ..

Comment: @Rajakumar, if I understand your comment correctly, you don't have to save the data entry offset between calls, since the function will not fill the buffer with incomplete entries. It will keep trying to accommodate the current entry until you supply a buffer large enough to hold it.

Comment: ok then how can get right amount of Length to allocate buffer by calling zwquerydirectoryfile(twice)..once for to know abt required length and another call to fetch full data to given length....is it possible like normal query related apis to know abt buffer length(required) by assign buffer as NULL...

Comment: @Rajakumar, I see what you mean, but `ZwQueryDirectoryFile()` doesn't work like that. It will not (and probably cannot) tell you the buffer size needed to accommodate the remaining file system entries. You might want to incrementally grow the buffer until the function succeeds. On the other hand, 4096 bytes *should* be more than enough to fit a single entry, so you can use a fixed-size buffer and process the entries one by one.